# Setting coordinate Grid with map composer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinates, print-composer, grids-graticules

I have been trying to display a coordinate grid on my map with QGIS.

I have a shapefile projected to UTM zone 34N. I have set the CRS to "WGS 84 Zone 34N" on the main properties tab and the same for map grid properties on the CRS tab. My interval is map units. Unfortunately, I am definitely missing or doing something wrong and I get some weird lines at the corners (see image) of my map and the same when I change the interval to cm.
[image]

[image]

My main goal is to display normal coordinate grid on my map. If you can guide me on this or any input about the process of doing this correctly.

Comment: do you really want a 1cm grid? try a interval of 100000m or switch the CRS to 4326 and use degrees

Comment: What scale has your map? What values have you tried?